# get last 6 items from array js after original array has been filtered

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array and currently it gets me the first 6 items from the array after it has been filtered to only include todays games.

```
fixtures.filter(fixture => {
    return fixture.date === today;
}).slice(0, 6);
```

This works fine, but I want to get the last 6 items from the array after it has been filtered. I have tried the following but it doesn't work for me.

```
fixtures.filter((fixture, index, arr) => {
    return fixture.date === today;
}).slice(Math.max(arr.length - 6, 1));
```

It is saying that `arr` is undefined. Is there a way of doing this in one chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.slice(-6)` to get the last 6 elements of the array. [A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Parameters).

```
fixtures.filter(fixture => {
    return fixture.date === today;
}).slice(-6);
```